# How can I refer to F# names containing a single quote in a C# context?

Tags: syntax, f#

This mostly comes up while trying to debug F# code in the Visual Studio debugger, which expects C# syntax:

> The debugger does not recognize F# expressions. To enter an expression in a debugger window or a dialog box during F# debugging, you must translate the expression into C# syntax. When you translate an F# expression into C#, make sure to remember that C# uses == as the comparison operator for equality and that F# uses a single =.

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee843932.aspx)

The problem is that I have variables and functions that contain single quote characters, like `path'`, but single quotes seem not to be valid in names in C#, so entering `path'` in the debugger window just says `Newline expected in constant` or words to that effect, because it thinks I am starting a character literal. Even right-clicking on it and adding a watch via the contextual menu gives a similar error.

How can I translate F# names containing single quotes into C# syntax, so that I can inspect them from the debugger or refer to them from C# code?

Comment: A lot of the F# intrinsic functions are aliased with names adhering to the Framework Design Guidelines. I assume there is an Attribute which can be added to a function which controls its external name in the IL. (I know this doesn't directly solve the problem but it may give you ideas/options)

Comment: You might be able to use reflection. Are you just translating F# code to C#, or are you actually calling F# from C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to do this - so the best option is probably to rename the variable `path'` to some other name that is a valid C# identifier like `pathAux`.

Although F# is more flexible with naming (and allows things like `path'` or even ``` ``whatever !`` ```), it is probably a good idea to use C#-compatible identifier names most of the times, because it will make the code readable to a wider audience - such as C# developers.

Comment: Unfortunately, not my code, and wading through it with sed would seem impolite. But thanks for your input. I'll accept your answer in a few days if nothing else turns up.

Comment: @BenMillwood Makes sense - Even if you wanted to change the code, you might want to wait until the F# Power Tools authors add support for rename refactoring :-) (hopefully coming soon!) http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff